# Не получается разобраться с регуляркой по C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET","show_city1.php?state_code="+str,true);
```

Нужно выдернуть все между: ("GET"," и "+ , то есть выдернуть кусок: `show_city1.php?state_code=` без лишних символов в начале и в конце, какой примерный патерн  использовать для этого? Подскажите, пожалуйста, патерн нужен под C#...

Comment: То есть вы пытаетесь распарсить js-код? о_О
Вы делаете что-то запредельное. Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Comment: настоящая задача спарсить: show_city1.php?state_code= регуляркой, вроде все понятно изложил суть выше, код не js он присутствует как текст в контенте веб страницы в открытом виде, тоесть нужен сам патерн правильный...

Comment: Угу, а завтра разрабы превратят его в `new Url("show_city" + city_num + ".aspx").addQuery("state_code", str)`. Ваш подход к проблеме («выцепить текст из html-страницы») в принципе неверен. И да, это не может быть настоящей задачей. Это часть вашего подхода к решению какой-то бОльшей проблемы.

Comment: @VladD не вижу ничего необычного в задаче. Типично для сборщиков данных которые не имеют нормального открытого экспорта. Встречается довольно часто (в некоторых областях). И да, это решение обречено на постоянное обновление, что не снимает её необходимости (если частота обновления имеет разумные сроки и/или овчинка стоит выделки).

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: давайте тогда называть вещи своими именами: сборщик данных с сайта, создатели которого вовсе не хотят, чтобы эти данные собирались. (Иначе они бы открыли API.)

Comment: Вы не знаете хотят они этого или нет, более того я просто привел пример реальной задачи. И это не имеет отношения к технической стороне вопроса.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: Всегда, когда приходится парсить бесформатные данные, у меня возникает вопрос: почему надо получать информацию не из исходной объектной структуры, а из какого-то текста, который из этой самой структуры получается, и не предназначен авторами для парсинга. В нормальной ситуации (когда владелец объектной структуры сотрудничает) мне просто не приходится иметь дело с текстом.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: По поводу технической стороны вопроса: если автор очевидным образом [забивает гвозди микроскопом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105), нет смысла обсуждать правильный хват.

Comment: @VladD не совсем понятен ваш аргумент. В данном случае и задача (парсинг текста/"забить гвоздь") и инструмент (регексп/"молоток") соответствуют друг другу. Я не вижу тут "микроскопа". Это даже не парсинг HTML, где можно было посоветовать работать с DOM через HtmlAgilityTools. *Возможно* автору можно было бы помочь лучше если бы он сделал более правильный вопрос, но и в таком виде вопрос вполне корректен на мой взгляд.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: Я пытаюсь посмотреть на задачу с более высокого уровня: поиск текстовых строк — неправильный метод для получения данных из сериализованной объектной структуры. Впрочем, мне кажется, что мы в офтопике здесь, это скорее обсуждение для чата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам регулярка (символы "/" в начале и конце не являются частью регулярки)

```
/xmlhttp\.open\("GET","(.+?)"/
```

Код на C#:

```
        var content =  "xmlhttp.open(\"GET\",\"show_city1.php?state_code=\"+str,true);";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(content , "xmlhttp\\.open\\(\"GET\",\"(.+?)\"");
        var result = matches[0].Groups[1];
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вывод:

> show_city1.php?state_code=

Comment: А как экранировать?  var matches = Regex.Matches(content , @"xmlhttp\.open\("GET","(.+?)""); если так ставить то ошибки идут...

Comment: ошибки обойти через дополнительную переменную так же не выходит...

Comment: @GeneratorSveta Я добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Да все почти норм парсит, и код с Regex.Replace  ниже который тоже, но еще такой момент, в контенте присутсвует несколько схожих строк например xmlhttp.open("GET","show.php?country_code="
xmlhttp.open("GET","show_city1.php?state_code="  а парсится тока первый  попавшийся: show.php?country_code= как парсить все аналогичные куски из контента?

Comment: Вот полный код: var matches = Regex.Matches(content , "xmlhttp\\.open\\(\"GET\",\"(.+?)\"");
                                var result = matches[0].Groups[1];


                                lock (this.lockValid)
                                    this.valid++;

                                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Out.txt" , true);
                                writer.WriteLine("http://" + str3 + "/" + result);
                                writer.Close();  но сохраняется тока как и писал выше первый попавшийся только,надо чтобы все подходящие сохранялись из контента

Comment: как этот момент лучше решить предлагаете?

Comment: полный матч находит все но по группам сохраняется тока первый попавшийся...

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли использовать `Regex.Replace`? Захватите, то что надо, а что не надо - просто удалите заменой:

```
var text = "xmlhttp.open(\"GET\",\"show_city1.php?state_code=\"+str,true);";
var result2 = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?s).*""GET"",""([^""]+)"".*", "$1");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутренний модификатор `(?s)` изменяет поведение точки, которая теперь отлавливает также и знаки переноса строки.

Comment: честно признаюсь с Regex.Replace как то не пользовался особо раньше, вообще пробовал ваш вариант но сохраняет весь контент страницы, вообще вариант интересный но сложноватый по мойму...

Comment: Я добавил `(?s)`, теперь должно работать даже с многострочным текстом. НО! Если у Вас таких подстрок несколько, этот вариант не пройдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот например:

```
\("GET","(.+)"\+
```

в первой группе у вас будет нужная вам строка.

Comment: Тоже самое не как экранировать не выходит:  var matches = Regex.Matches(content , @"\(\"GET\",\"(.+)\"\+"); ошибки...

Comment: Чет я перемудрил, поправил регекс. Экранируйте как обычно, слешем.

Comment: да почти но парсятся и лишние символы: var matches = Regex.Matches(content , @"\(""GET"",""(.+)""\+"); тоесть парсятся такой вид: ("GET","show_city1.php?state_code="+ надо чтобы парсил тока эту часть: show_city1.php?state_code=

Comment: Правильно это полный матч, а вам нужна первая группа.

Comment: да по группам понял спасибо...

Comment: Вот полный код: var matches = Regex.Matches(content , "\\(\"GET\",\"(.+?)\"");lock (this.lockValid) this.valid++; StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Out.txt" , true); writer.WriteLine("http://" + str3 + "/" + result); writer.Close(); но сохраняется тока как и писал выше первый попавшийся только,надо чтобы все подходящие сохранялись из контента, как этот момент можете предложить решить?

Comment: Всё находит, вы просто используете первый. Идите циклом по всем элементам `matches`.