# Как выдернуть href= uri из html на С#?

Tags: c#

Как из такого кода:`<a href="thumbnails.php?album=10">` выдернуть часть между кавычками, то есть эту часть: `thumbnails.php?album=10` ? Вот мой код:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(content , "<a\\href=\"(.+?)");
var result = matches[0].Groups[1];
```

Ну похоже ошибка у меня не совсем то что нужно выдергивает, подскажите, правильный код пожалуйста...

Вот новый код выдергивает все но только с лишними данными типа начало и конца которых не надо сохранять:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(content , "<a.+href=\"(.+?)\"");

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match m in matches)
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Value))
        sb.AppendLine(m.Value.Trim());

lock (this.lockValid)
    this.valid++;

File.AppendAllText("Links.txt" , sb.ToString());
```

На выходе:

```
<a href="index.php?menu=exp&amp;mid=242&amp;s=6f7b7a8a0c8667e168bfd186b332e7ed"
<a href="/index.php?s=6f7b7a8a0c8667e168bfd186b332e7ed"
```

Как можно исключить лишние данные типа: `<a href="` и `"` еще как то исключить бы эту часть тоже:

```
&amp;mid=242&amp;s=6f7b7a8a0c8667e168bfd186b332e7ed"
```

Как можно решить это?

Comment: В `hhref` одну букву `h` уберите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
string content = "<a title=\"t\" href=\"thumbnails.php?album=10\"></a><a href=\"s2\"></a>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(content, "<a.+?href=\"(.+?)\"");
foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
```

**EDIT**
Код изменен для нахождения *всех* ссылок в строке.

Comment: не совсем то, еще какие варианты?

Comment: @GeneratorSveta почему именно "не совсем то"? в результате выполнения в переменной `result` содержится как раз то, а именно, цитирую: *часть между кавычками*.

Comment: @GeneratorSveta, надо смотреть оригинальную разметку. Возможно нужно воспользоваться дополнительными опциями Regex, такими как RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline

Comment: Например вот мой старый вопрос там есть пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445273/Не-получается-разобраться-с-регуляркой-по-c , я как раз и пытался подогнать под этот вопрос код который давали на той теме, точнее не сам код а регулярку от туда но не вышло, с вашим проверял пытался подогнать чет он вообще другое то что не нужно парсит, может оибка какая сами проверяли? этот код: '<a href="thumbnails.php?album=10">' из html страницы если что, хотя щас может сам ошибся проверю еще раз попробую...

Comment: такс да работает разобрался почти но выдергивает только первый попавшийся а не все что есть на странице, как это исправить можно?

Comment: @GeneratorSveta исправил.

Comment: ок спс щас попробую...

Comment: у вас под консоль подогнано а вот под дектоп как преобразовать посоветует?  например вот так не получится: var matches = Regex.Matches(content , "<a.+?href=\"(.+?)\"");
                                foreach (Match m in matches)
                                    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);

                                StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter("Links.txt" , true);
                                writer2.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
                                writer2.Close(); если преобразовать в строковую переменную то так же пишется первый попавшийся тока, не понятно.

Comment: @GeneratorSveta Чего? Ничего не понял. Если я ответил на ваш изначальный вопрос: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Если у вас есть дополнительные вопросы, пожалуйста, [задавайте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) их.

Comment: все разобрался спасибо большое, проблема решена сам чуть ошибся...